# Can't debug Django project in Aptana Studio

Tags: python, django, debugging, aptana

I am working on a Django web app in Aptana Studio, and have reached the point where it would be really nice to debug through Aptana. Unfortunately, whenever I try to do so, I get the following:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zdurtschi/Documents/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1479, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/home/zdurtschi/Documents/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1125, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  #execute the script
  File "/home/zdurtschi/Workspaces/DjangoSite/zadWebApp/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'zadWebApp.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named zadWebApp.settings
```

Following the answers for another question, I added the following to the end of my `settings.py`:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'zadWebApp.settings'

PYTHONPATH = "/home/user/Workspaces/DjangoSite/zadWebApp"
```

It used to give a whole bunch of errors, but between the above code, adding things to my project resources, and probably some other stuff, I've got it down to just this one. I'm using Aptana Studio 3.6 and Django 1.6. Everything runs fine using `./manage.py runserver` in a console. If I can provide any other helpful information, I'd be happy to add it.